# Is there a way to add role to top level role defined in role hierarchy

Tags: user, role-hierarchy

Our organization has role hierarchy defined as follows:

- A

  - B

    - B.a
    - B.b
  - C

I would like to add a parent to top level role 'A'. Is there any easy way to add this rather than rebuilding entire role hierarchy.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming A is the ultimate role in the hierarchy, you can just create a new role, then edit A to point to the new parent role. I don't see why you'd need to rebuild the entire role hierarchy.

Comment: @sfdcfox -- you should make this an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the entire hierarchy already reports to role A, as in your example, you can just create a new role, then edit role A to report to the new role. In this way, the new role will become the ultimate role in the hierarchy with just one edit.